# Using php hip-hop in cygwin

Tags: php, cygwin, hiphop

Is it possible to run hip-hop php in cygwin which is using more script languages in windows like linux environment...?

Comment: for anyone reading this now, There's a guide available [here](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-Installing-HHVM-on-Cygwin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mistaking about what [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is, it's an approximation of a standard *nix environment on windows, giving you access to a lot of tools and shells that you otherwise wouldn't have. It's not a linux system providing the necessary api and system calls, it can not run linux originating binaries.

So your actual question in my opinion is: "how can I run a hiphop generated compiled application under windows?" to which I have to say: for now you can't barring trying to compile the generated c++ source code yourself on windows.

for references see

- [run compiled file on windows (hiphop-php-dev)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/hiphop-php-dev/zzNeu-D-f_4/n3wy1s8M-QIJ)
- [about windows](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/hiphop-php-dev/zzNeu-D-f_4/n3wy1s8M-QIJ)

So right now your only real options are running it in a virtualized linux environment, on or besides Windows, wether that's worth it, I can't say.